# Почему не отрабатывает php-файл через крон?

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, crontab

Правило crontab:

```
/usr/local/php56/bin/php -c /home/****.ini  -f /*****/cron.sh
```

**cron.sh:**

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$fc = fopen(__DIR__ . "/cron1.txt", "a");
fwrite($fc, "");

require_once( __DIR__ . '/wp-load.php' ); //подключаем ядро вордпресс

$fc = fopen(__DIR__ . "/cron2.txt", "a");
fwrite($fc, "");
```

cron1.txt - создается, cron2.txt - нет, видимо, проблема с подключением ядра.

Через веб-интерфейс отрабатывает нормально, через крон нет. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: попробуйте после записи добавить `fclose($fc)`

Comment: Смотрите логи - какие ошибки вываливаются при обращении к wp-load.php. Учтите, что wp-load.php запускает не только ядро, но и все плагины. Довольно часто встречаются криво написанные плагины, которые не любят запуск через CLI и падают.

Comment: как минимум разница — в отсутствии переменных окружения, устанавливаемых http-сервером. попробуйте их воссоздать.

Answer (score 0):

wp-load.php видимо должен запускаться через web, а через крон оно не умеет. Скорее всего где-то с путями проблемы внутри него. 
Подозреваю что если после require_once( **DIR** . '/wp-load.php' ); написать echo 'hello world' оно тоже не отработает.

Comment: Это не так. wp-load.php прекрасно работает через cron, я делал это.

Comment: Поделитесь скриптом, как у вас отрабатывал этот файл с кроном.

Comment: @Сергей Да в моем скрипте ничего необычного нет,. Смотрите логи.